# Conversion from QGIS Layer to KML file, to then Google MY maps. Layer brings to blank map?

Tags: qgis, google-maps, kml, google-mymaps

[image]

This is what I see upon importing my KML file to Google My Maps. Is the file size of 503 kb too big? My CRS is EPSG:4326 like Google Maps.

Anything to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked by zooming out? Also, your data is polygon, but the google maps is probably showing as polylines. Did you upload the correct data? You can try changing the style to uniform style by clicking the individual styles.

Comment: Have your tried running ST_MakeValid before the export?

Comment: Google  Maps uses EPSG 3857 and Google Earth uses EPSG: 4326 see one of the highest upvoted answers here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/48952/276

Comment: @Mapperz though Google Earth never actually used EPSG:4326, it used WGS 84 lon/lat (as does KML ~ http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/0/LonLat84) and Google Maps now I think is no longer EPSG:3857 (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302795/what-is-the-new-projection-for-google-maps-called)